# Algorithm to solve a physical ring removal puzzle

Tags: algorithms

Assume we want to solve the so-called "Super-G" problem from Jean-Claude Constantin. The goal of the puzzle is to get the ring off the other components. Here is a picture of the problem:

[image: Picture of Super-G problem]
Source: http://gunnarmp.blogspot.com/2016/10/super-g.html

The question here shall not be how to do that - that's trivial after you figured out. The question shall be, how we can write a simulation for this problem that seeks for the proper solution.

I can think of two completely different approaches, both of them non-trivial:

- May we find a way to represent all moves that we can do in an abstract way? The simulation would be trivial.
- Should we use a 3D simulation and use some random walk to move the ring? The set-up might be much simpler, but the simulation itself much harder, also because the line might be very hard to simulate.

We are not looking for a solution in the form of a code, but what approach should be taken.

Comment: I am not sure where to post this question. If there is a better stackexchange page, please let me know.

Comment: Techniques from motion planning in robotics may be useful, though I'm not familiar enough with the area to say more.

Comment: You may also be able to borrow inspiration from knot theory to abstract the legal moves

Comment: @eru-cs That's an interesting hint.  Never heard about this and interesting to read about this.